# What defines object's state?

Tags: java, multithreading, object, concurrency

According to Java Concurrency in Practice book:

> Informally, an object's state is its data, stored in state variables such as instance or static fields.

As far as I understand from Java concepts or in general, state / instance variables define the object state. As far as I know, the static fields belong to class variables. In what case does static fields define object's state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds a bit ambiguous to me - one could probably argue that static variables are inherently object state that is the same for all objects of a given type.

Personally, however I don't think that static variables constitute **object state**.  This quote from the [Oracle Java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) seems to support my understanding.

> Sometimes, you want to have variables that are common to all objects.
>   This is accomplished with the static modifier. Fields that have the
>   static modifier in their declaration are called static fields or class
>   variables. **They are associated with the class, rather than with any
>   object**. Every instance of the class shares a class variable, which is
>   in one fixed location in memory. Any object can change the value of a
>   class variable, but class variables can also be manipulated without
>   creating an instance of the class.
>
> For example, suppose you want to create a number of Bicycle objects
>   and assign each a serial number, beginning with 1 for the first
>   object. This ID number is unique to each object and is therefore an
>   instance variable. At the same time, you need a field to keep track of
>   how many Bicycle objects have been created so that you know what ID to
>   assign to the next one. **Such a field is not related to any individual
>   object, but to the class as a whole**.

With that said, static variables can keep track of the status of the overall application state, which is what another question based on the same books speaks to: [Object's state in public static fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35111182/objects-state-in-public-static-fields)

Comment: Oh I got it. It triggered something in my brain. Thanks for your answer and for the link.

Answer (score 0):

From Wiki

> In object-oriented programming, there is also the concept of a static
>   member variable, which is a "class variable" of a statically defined
>   class, i.e., a member variable of a given class which is shared across
>   all instances (objects), and is accessible as a member variable of
>   these objects

Since static variable in class is shared across all the instances (objects) of class, it plays a role directly or indirectly in state of that object.